# Merging dataframes with time series data + checking if values already exist in the first df

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new at Python so please bear with me. I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df1
    Company  1/2020   2/2020
     Apple   1          0
     Google  0          2
```

I want to be able to merge a new data frame that may look like:

```
df2
   Company  2/2020   3/2020
     Apple   1          1
     Google  2          0
```

How do I join the two df's and is there a way to overwrite the value if the new value is greater?

I tried using just a merge and a join function and neither worked.

Comment: Please include code that can be copy and pasted to generate your two test dfs. Also describe how neither join or merge worked? What is the result you want?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand the intent of the question.
If the sum of `df1+df2` is required, the following code can be used.

```
 import pandas as pd
 import io

 data = '''
 Company 1/2020 2/2020
 Apple 1 0
 Google 0 2
 '''

 data2 = '''
 Company 2/2020 3/2020
 Apple 1 1
 Google 2 0
 '''
 df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=' ')
 df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data2), sep=' ')

 df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=0).fillna(0).groupby('Company').agg(sum)

 df3
        1/2020  2/2020  3/2020
 Company            
 Apple   1.0    1   1.0
 Google  0.0    4   0.0
```